# How do I change the color of my check mark in a ui:inputcheckbox?

Tags: lightning, checkbox, style

I am trying to set the color of my check mark. This is the code:

```
<div class="slds-form-element__row">
    <div class="slds-form-element">
        <label class="slds-checkbox">
            <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="marketing" class="slds-input" value="{!v.identityRequest.Marketing__c}" change="{!c.onChange}" />
            <span class="slds-checkbox--faux"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: example]

This is how it needs to look like.

Reading the documentation leaves me a bit confused, anybody an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
        <label class="slds-checkbox">
            <ui:inputCheckbox value="" />
            <span class="slds-checkbox--faux" />
            <span class="slds-form-element__label">Checkbox</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    </div>
```

If it works mark it as best answer!

Comment: please see the edit that I made to see the example of my checkbox

Answer (score 0):

That is also available:

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
<div class="slds-form-element__control" style="padding: 100px;">
    <label class="slds-checkbox">
        <ui:inputCheckbox value="" />
        <span class="slds-checkbox--faux" />
        <span class="slds-form-element__label">Checkbox</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

and apply style as:

```
<style>
    .slds-checkbox--faux{

        background: #000!important;
    }
    .slds-checkbox [type=checkbox]:checked+.slds-checkbox_faux:after, .slds-checkbox [type=checkbox]:checked+.slds-checkbox--faux:after, .slds-checkbox [type=checkbox]:checked~.slds-checkbox_faux:after, .slds-checkbox [type=checkbox]:checked~.slds-checkbox--faux:after, .slds-checkbox [type=checkbox]:checked+.slds-checkbox__label .slds-checkbox_faux:after, .slds-checkbox [type=checkbox]:checked+.slds-checkbox__label .slds-checkbox--faux:after{
        border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
        border-left: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 23855);
    } 
</style>
```

This will work for the above output you want.
If that works please mark it as best answer.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. The second style (.slds-checkbox) is not accepted. I am not able to save it. because I am getting an error: '[ERROR]: Issue(s) found by CSS Parser (0Ad5E0000004VPY): Only pseudo-classes are allowed after the pseudo-element ':after''. How do I solve this?

Comment: It seems you are you trying to save it in the style section of lightning? Try saving it in the component section itself just under style tags

Comment: Did this work in the end?, I am trying something simalar Where then the checkbox is selected i want it to become red instead of the SF Blue. I have attempted css toggling within the js controller however this change will happen before the lightning css is applied and therefore overwritten. 
I have set to get the above method to work.